# Run-time error "13": in my VBA excel code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a script that will count a numbers of days between few separate dates.  I have a data in cell like:

> 1-In Progress#02-ASSIGNED TO TEAM#22/01/2013 14:54:23,4-On
>   Hold#02-ASSIGNED TO TEAM#18/01/2013 16:02:03,1-In Progress#02-ASSIGNED
>   TO TEAM#18/01/2013 16:02:03

That's the info about my transaction status. I want to count the numbers of days that this transaction was in "4-On Hold". So in this example it will be between 18/01/2013 and 22/01/2013.

I wrote something like this(sorry for ma native language words in text)

```
Sub Aktywnywiersz()
    Dim wiersz, i, licz As Integer
    Dim tekstwsadowy As String
    Dim koniectekstu As String
    Dim pozostalytekst As String
    Dim dataztekstu As Date
    Dim status4jest As Boolean
    Dim status4byl As Boolean
    Dim datarozpoczecia4 As Date
    Dim datazakonczenia4 As Date
    Dim dniw4 As Long


    wiersz = 2 'I start my scrypt from second row of excel

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(wiersz, "A")) 'this should work until there is any text in a row

        status4jest = False 'is status 4-On Hold is now in a Loop
        status4byl = False 'is status 4-On Hold was in las loop
        dniw4 = 0 ' numbers od days in 4-On Hold status
        tekstwsadowy = Cells(wiersz, "H").Value2 'grabing text
        tekstwsadowy = dodanieprzecinka(tekstwsadowy) 'in some examples I had to add a coma at the end of text

        For i = 1 To Len(tekstwsadowy)
          If Right(Left(tekstwsadowy, i), 1) = "," Then licz = licz + 1  'count the number of comas in text that separates the changes in status
        Next

        For j = 1 To licz

            koniectekstu = funkcjaliczeniadni(tekstwsadowy) 'take last record after coma
            Cells(wiersz, "k") = koniectekstu

            dataztekstu = funkcjadataztekstu(koniectekstu) 'take the date from this record
            Cells(wiersz, "m") = dataztekstu

            status4jest = funkcjaokreslenia4(koniectekstu) 'check if there is 4-On Hold in record
            Cells(wiersz, "n") = status4jest


            If (status4byl = False And staus4jest = True) Then

                datarozpoczecia4 = dataztekstu
                status4byl = True

            ElseIf (status4byl = True And staus4jest = False) Then
                datazakonczenia4 = dataztekstu
                status4byl = False  'if elseif funkcion to check information about 4-On Hold
                dniw4 = funkcjaobliczeniadniw4(dniw4, datazakonczenia4, datarozpoczecia4) 'count days in 4-On Hold

            Else
                  'Else not needed...
            End If


            tekstwsadowy = resztatekstu(tekstwsadowy, koniectekstu) 'remove last record from main text

        Next

        Cells(wiersz, "L") = dniw4 ' show number of days in 4-On Hold status


        wiersz = wiersz + 1
    Loop
End Sub


Function funkcjaliczeniadni(tekstwsadowy As String)

    Dim a, dl As Integer
    dl = Len(tekstwsadowy)

    a = 0

On Error GoTo errhandler:

    Do Until a > dl
        a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(",", tekstwsadowy, a + 1)
    Loop

    funkcjaliczeniadni = tekstwsadowy
    Exit Function
errhandler:
    funkcjaliczeniadni = Right(tekstwsadowy, dl - a)

End Function


Function dodanieprzecinka(tekstwsadowy As String)

    If Right(tekstwsadowy, 1) = "," Then
        dodanieprzecinka = Left(tekstwsadowy, Len(tekstwsadowy) - 1)
    Else
        dodanieprzecinka = tekstwsadowy
    End If

End Function


Function resztatekstu(tekstwsadowy, koniectekstu As String)

    resztatekstu = Left(tekstwsadowy, Len(tekstwsadowy) - Len(koniectekstu))

End Function


Function funkcjadataztekstu(koniectekstu As String)

    funkcjadataztekstu = Right(koniectekstu, 19)
    funkcjadataztekstu = Left(funkcjadataztekstu, 10)

End Function


Function funkcjaobliczeniadniw4(dniw4 As Long, datazakonczenia4 As Date, datarozpoczecia4 As Date)

    Dim liczbadni As Integer

    liczbadni = DateDiff(d, datarozpoczecia4, datazakonczenia4)
    funkcjaobliczaniadniw4 = dniw4 + liczbadni

End Function

Function funkcjaokreslenia4(koniectekstu As String)

    Dim pierwszyznak As String

    pierwszyznak = "4"

    If pierszyznak Like Left(koniectekstu, 1) Then
        funkcjaokreslenia4 = True
    Else
        funkcjaokreslenia4 = False
    End If

End Function
```

And for now I get

> Run-time error "13"

in

```
dataztekstu = funkcjadataztekstu(koniectekstu) 'take the date from this record
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi, in your code i see a lot of undeclared variables. Do you know the Option Explicit? If you do not use it, try it here. Write it in the very first line of your code. Then in VBA editor go to Debug -> Compile and check if all your variables are well declared.

Comment: Thx for help. This option helps a lot. I'm figthing with that now:)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because of Type Mismatch. `dataztekstu` is declared as a date and most probably the expression which is being returned by the function `funkcjadataztekstu` is not a date. You will have to step through it to find what value you are getting in return.

Here is a simple example to replicate that problem

This will give you that error

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim dt As String
    Dim D As Date

    dt = "Blah Blah"

    D = getdate(dt)

    Debug.Print D
End Sub

Function getdate(dd As String)
    getdate = dd
End Function
```

This won't

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim dt As String
    Dim D As Date

    dt = "12/12/2014"

    D = getdate(dt)

    Debug.Print D
End Sub

Function getdate(dd As String)
    getdate = dd
End Function
```

If you change your function to this

```
Function funkcjadataztekstu(koniectekstu As String)
    Dim temp As String

    temp = Right(koniectekstu, 19)
    temp = Left(temp, 10)

    MsgBox temp '<~~ This will tell you if you are getting a valid date in return

    funkcjadataztekstu = temp
End Function
```

Then you can see what that function is returning.

Comment: Thx for help. I get a clear box, so thats the problem i need to solve now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code, but it is a little difficult to understand just what it is that you want to do. Part of it is the code in your language, but the code is also hard to read beacuse of the lack of indentation etc. :)

Also, I do not understand how the data in the worksheet looks. I did get it running by guessing, though, and when I did I got the same error you are describing on the second run of the For loop - that was because the `koniectekstu` string was empty. Not sure if this is your problem, so my solution is a very general.

In order to solve this type of problem:

1. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module. This will make you have to declare *all* variables used in the module, and you will remove many of the problems you have before you run the code. Eg you are declaring a variable `status4jest` but using a different variable called `staus4jest` and Excel will not complain unless you use `Option Explicit`.
2. Declare return types for your functions.
3. Format your code so it will be easier to read. Use space before and after statements. Comment everything! You have done some, but make sure a beginner can understand. I will edit you code as an example of indentation.
4. **Debug**! Step through your code using <kbd>F8</kbd> and make sure all variables contain what you think they do. You will most likely solve your problem by debugging the code this way.
5. Ask for help here on specific problems you run into or how to solve specific problems, do not send all the code and ask why it is not working. If you break down your problems into parts and ask separately, you will learn VBA yourself a lot faster.
6. A specific tip regarding your code: look up the `Split` function. It can take a string and make an array based on a delimiter - Example: `Split(tekstwsadowy, ",")` will give you an array of strings, with the text between the commas.
7. Did I mention `Option Explicit`? ;)

Anyway, I hope this helps, even if I did not solve the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I use 'Option Explicit' and i correct some errors. For example as you describe 'staus4jest' should be 'status4jest':) i will tray with Split function and go with info if i'm succeeded with my problem:)